# Create Dynamic checkboxes by iterating JSONArray in DOJO

Tags: javascript, checkbox, dojo

I am new to DOJO and I am using **DOJO 1.5.0 version**.

I want to create dynamic checkboxes by iterating JSONArray in DOJO. This dynamic creation will be done on a particular event like when we selecting some combo-box value.

For example consider below JSONArray:

> var tempJSONArray = [{role_id = '1', role_name = 'role1'},{role_id =
>   '2', role_name = 'role2'},{role_id = '3', role_name = 'role3'}]

I want display checkboxes corresponding to Role Name. Lable for checkbox will be role_name  and value will be role_id from JSON object.
Also I want to add 'onChange' event to check-boxes, as on this event I want to do a Ajax call to server with role_ids.

Thank you for reading and also please let me know if further clarification is needed.

Comment: You need to show us what you have tried so far. Asking for solutions without any effort will not attract much answers.

Comment: If you are new to DOJO why are you working with version 1.5.0?

Comment: @ThomasKagan: Project is already build with version 1.5.0 and I am new member in Team. I need to add one functionality in existing project.Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some internet surfing and playing around code I able write below code, which working fine for my scenario. So thought it will be helpful for others.

```
for ( var i = 0; i < roleJSON.length; i++) {
                        var role = roleJSON[i]; 
                        var tr = dojo.create("tr",{id:"rolebasecheckbox"+i,'class':'rolebasecheckbox'});
                        alert("tr=" + tr);
                        var td= dojo.create("td",{innerHTML:'<input id="roleBaseCb_'+i+'" value="'+role.role_id+'" dojoType="dijit.form.CheckBox" onclick="alert('onclick event')" type="checkbox" /> <label for="roleBaseCb_'+i+'">'+role.role_name+'</label>',align:'center'},tr);
                        alert("td=" + td);
                        if(i==0){
                        alert("i is 0");
                        dojo.place(tr, "roleBaseComboTR", "after");
                        }else{
                            dojo.place(tr, "rolebasecheckbox"+(i-1), "after");  
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: That indeed uses the tools I mentioned, `dojo.place()` and `dojo.create()`. Though, I don't really recommend creating Dijit widgets like that.. either make them declaratively by placing them in the HTML, or make them programmatically using the correct API's. Making declarative styled widgets in JavaScript just sounds wrong to me.

Comment: @Dimitri M : Yes and Thanks for your help. First I tried to make them programmatically but its not worked for my scenario so I have created using above way. But from next time will try or insure to make it programmtically or declarative.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `dojo.create()` method for creating DOM nodes and the `dojo.place()` method for placing them inside another element, for example:

```
var checkbox = dojo.create("input", {
    type: "checkbox",
    value: "1"
});
```

You will probably have to wrap it inside a `<label>` to show the text (which you can also create with `dojo.create()`). Then you can place them inside a list, for example:

```
dojo.place(label, "checkboxes");
```

This will wrap the checkbox (or label) inside an element with ID `checkboxes`. So, if you create your checkboxes now inside a loop, it should work.